# serverless rest api gateway nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

hey how can i get params data?

```
// this is serverless.yml
test_function:
    handler: handler.test
    events:
    - http:
        path: "registry/{some_data}"
        method: get
        request:
          template:
            application/json: >
              {
                "damn": "$input.params('some_data')"
              }

// this is handle.js
module.exports.test= (event, context, cb) => {
  cb(null, { bangke: 'Dorrrrr !!'+event.some_data});
};
```

but event.some_data print undefine
anyone know whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to pass a path argument. In this case use the following:

In `serverless.yml`:

```
test_function:
  handler: handler.test
  events:
    - http:
        path: registry/{some_data}
        method: get
```

In `handler.js`:

```
module.exports.test= (event, context, cb) => {
  cb(null, { bangke: 'Dorrrrr !!'+ event.path.some_data});
};
```